# Flash Messages are unreliable, how to fix this case?

Tags: php, flash-message

Nobody replied to this question a few days ago, so I will try to explain it in a different way. This is keeping me locked from working at my project.

In PHP, you can store feedback messages on $_SESSION such as $_SESSION['login'] = "failed", which can be reported back to an user after a redirection. These are called flash messages. The problem is that PHP has no idea which flash message belongs to which browser TAB. Here is an example:

1. An user goes to website.com/UploadPhoto on two tabs, and selects one photo to upload on each. He hits send on both at about the same time.
2. The first photo gets processed by a form, and is uploaded successfully. The flash message saves as "success!", and the redirection begins back to website.com/myPhotos/ so the user can upload more photos and also see the success flash message displayed - but here is the catch, the user was randomly selected for an AD, and it will take him 10 seconds to be redirected to his photo page.
3. The second image is being processed by a form now, but it has an error, and gets a flash message of "error: file too big", and the redirection proceeds back to website.com/UploadPhoto as well.

   What happens now, is that the second picture, which was uploaded after the first, gets redirected first with a message: Success! It hijacked the first one's message because it got redirected sooner. Then, after the 10 Ad second, the image 1 case gets redirected with the message "file too big" because it arrived later.

   How can you prevent this?
   I really hope someone can give me some insight because I'm stuck at my project because of this

Comment: Use Ajax or invisible iframe, where you'll post the form, get the answer and show it or redirect anywhere else.

Comment: PHP sessions are stored on a per-client basis. If you want to track mulitple windows/tabs then you need to implement that logic yourself.

Comment: You could pass the session id to your url or even have another parameter to help manage your error messages instead of a flash message. e.g. ?error=size etc.

Comment: Sorry Cheery but I don't understand your example for the iframe. The flash message happens after a redirect, so are you telling me I need to redirect with POST data? which would also cause the browser to ask for Form Resubmission if the user hit F5.

Comment: As for your example Eliel, I'm aware of it, or passing simply the ID of the error to match the flash message, but I'd rather keep the urls clean if possible

Comment: And Sammitch, my question is exactly how to do that

Answer (score 1):

When a browser performs a request to a certain url, it sends along all cookies that match the domain and path. It doesn't matter which window or tab your in, this behavior is always the same.

There are a couple of solutions to your problem:

#### Javascript / ajax

In my opinion the easiest way, because there are a lot of good javascript libraries for managing file uploads through XHR (ajax) requests. One I like is [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

In this case you won't need flash messages, you can simply put all the info you need in the response back to the XHR request.

#### Provide an id for the window/tab

Jens-André Koch gave a good answer of how this works.

#### Separate sessions

If you want full support for separate sessions for every window / tab, you can't rely on the session id being stored in a cookie. This however will mean that a user shall have to log in to every window / tab. I'll explain how this works in detail:

- A user visits https://my.domain.com/ and is provided a form to log in with.
- He/she fills out this form and hits the submit button. The browser performs a POST request.
- The server receives this request, sees the input is correct, stores the logged in state in new session, and sends a 30x response containing the url https://my.domain.com/upload/?session_name=session_id
- The browser reacts to this response by performing a GET request to that url.
- The server recognizes the session id in the url and resumes that session, sees the logges in state, and sends a 200 response containing a form to upload a file. The action attribute of the form element shoud contain the session id (https://my.domain.com/upload/?session_name=session_id).
- The user fills out the upload form and hits the submit button. The browser performs a POST request.
- The server receives the request and handles the file upload. 2 things can happen now:

  1. Failure:

     - The server sends a 200 response containing an error message and the original file upload form. The user can try again.
  2. Success:

     - The server stores a success flash message in the session, and send a 30x response containing the url http://my.domain.com/upload/?session_name=session_id.
     - The browser reacts to this response by performing a GET request to that url.
     - The server receives the request, sees there's a flash message in the session, and sends a 200 response containing the flash message (which is then removed from the session) along with the file upload form.

You should get the gist by now: every url that is returned by the server must contain the session id. You no longer rely on the session id in a cookie (in fact it's wise to disable sending a cookie containing the session id in PHP).

I've also been very explicit about requests / responses to better illustrates how the http protocol actually works.

Comment: You mean I need to give the user a new session ID with session_regenerate_id(false) after each flash message is saved, and then save that ID along with the flash message data?

Comment: A user needs to have a different session (login) on each tab, yes. If your goal is to upload multiple files at once, go for an ajax solution (far more user-friendly).

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see how what you said can be used to fix the problem of Flash message hijacking

Comment: The flash message is stored in a session which is identified by the session-id. When all tabs use a separate session by passing the session-id through something other than a cookie (like GET or POST data) the message will end up in the correct tab.

Comment: I know that using post data with the redirection can let me get the proper message (in fact, if you are using post, you don't even need to save flash messages in a $_SESSION variable), the problem is that if the user refreshes the redirected page, it will give the Form Resubmission window on most browsers

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to be more explicit, I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Your flashmessages have no idea, when and for which reason they should show.
When an image upload finishes, you might show the flashmessage depending on an image identifier.

To get a message like "Success: Image 1 from Tab A uploaded", you need to add more data to the session, for example the image id and maybe the status of the upload progress. If you really need the tab identifier, then add that, too.

- `$_SESSION['flashmessages']['image_uploads'][$id]['state'] = "uploading";`
- `$_SESSION['flashmessages']['image_uploads'][$id]['state'] = "finished";`

  ```
  if(array_key_exists('image_uploads', $_SESSION['flashmessages']) === true) 
  {
      foreach($_SESSION['flashmessages']['image_uploads'] as $image => $values) {
          if($values['state'] === 'finished') {
             // output flashmessage
             echo 'Success: Image ' . $image . ' was uploaded.';
             // unset this flashmessage
             unset($_SESSION['flashmessages']['image_uploads'][$id]);
          }
      }
  }
  ```